# What is the data type that is saved from a dialog box?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

As the title says, I'm wondering what data type is returned when a user presses enter on a dialog box, specifically from a self-created dialog box in a google spreadsheet, as I was under the impression it would be an array. More specifically, I have a dialog box that appears that allows text user input. This input is then supposed to be saved from the dialog box to cells in a google spreadsheet. Currently it only displays `undefined Vessels` for each of the cells. Below is the relevant code:

```
function setVesselCounts(data){
  let keys = scs.getRange(6,1,12,1).getDisplayValues()
  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    scs.getRange(6,3,6+i).setValue(data[i] + " Vessels")
  }
}
```

Below is the html used to create the dialog box, as well as the JS inside the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      p {display: table-row; }
      label { display: table-cell; }
      input { display: table-cell; }
    </style>
    <script>
      function setVesselCounts(){
        let controls = {}
        document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]").forEach(input => controls[input.id] = input.value)
        validateInput(controls) ? google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).setVesselCounts(controls) : window.alert('Please Check Input')
      }

      function validateInput(controls){
        return (
          controls["LA/LB"].value != '' &&
          controls["Oakland"].value != '' &&
          controls["Tacoma"].value != '' &&
          controls["Seattle"].value != '' &&
          controls["Vancouver"].value != ''&&
          controls["Halifax"].value != '' &&
          controls["NY"].value != '' &&
          controls["Norfolk"].value != '' &&
          controls["Charleston"].value != '' &&
          controls["Savannah"].value != '' &&
          controls["Mobile"].value != '' &&
          controls["Houston"].value != ''
        )
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  
  
  <body>
    <div>
      <table class="vessel-form">
        <p>
          <label for="LA/LB">LA/LB: </label><input type="text" id="LA/LB" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="Oakland">Oakland: </label><input type="text" id="Oakland">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="Tacoma">Tacoma: </label><input type="text" id="Tacoma">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="Seattle">Seattle: </label><input type="text" id="Seattle">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="Vancouver">Vancouver: </label><input type="text" id="Vancouver">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="Halifax">Halifax: </label><input type="text" id="Halifax">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="New York">New York: </label><input type="text" id="NY">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="Norfolk">Norfolk: </label><input type="text" id="Norfolk">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="Charleston">Charleston: </label><input type="text" id="Charleston">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="Savannah">Savannah: </label><input type="text" id="Savannah">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="Mobile">Mobile: </label><input type="text" id="Mobile">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="Houston">Houston: </label><input type="text" id="Houston">
        </p>
      </table>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" class="action" onclick="setVesselCounts()" >
      <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Finally is a screenshot of the created dialog box[image]

Comment: What is `data`, where does it come from?

Comment: @TheWizEd data comes from a dialog box that allows text user input. I will attach a copy of what the dialog box looks like, as well as the accompanying html

Comment: `data[i]` where `i` is an number doesn't match your `constrols.id` for example `LA/LB`

Comment: @TheWizEd So would you recommend a forEach loop that takes every element from the data object and checks it with the keys array (which contains all of the same acronyms), to see if they match, and if they do, then paste it in the corresponding cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your values are contiguous, capture the values in an array and use only one `setValues()` instead of repeated `setValue()`.  Note that I am constructing a 2D array in `rows`.

Change

```
function setVesselCounts(data){
  let keys = scs.getRange(6,1,12,1).getDisplayValues()
  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    scs.getRange(6,3,6+i).setValue(data[i] + " Vessels")
  }
}
```

To

```
function setVesselCounts(data){
  let keys = scs.getRange(6,1,12,1).getDisplayValues();
  let rows = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
    rows.push([data[keys[i][0]] + " Vessels"]);
  }
  scs.getRange(6,3,12,1).setValues(rows);
}
```

Reference

- [Spreadsheet Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: This worked, thank you. I do want to clarify something however, just to make sure I'm understanding everything correctly. When calling ```data[keys[i][0]]```, the value from the data element's id that matches the key is what is returned, right?

Comment: What ever the user typed in the dialog box.  Typically from <input> it is a string.  However when it is copied to the spreadsheet, the spreadsheet will coerce strings into numbers if it can.